# simulate xcode without development account

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

We have an app in Xcode from our old developers. We are in the registration process for an apple developer account, but on internet I read it can take a couple of weeks before it gets approved.

Is there a way I can simulate the app (like with TestFlight) without sending the actual code to potential new developers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't distribute the app unless you have it signed/provisioned with needed UDIDs (which requires developer program). You can deploy it on your(s) device(s) using XCode though.

Answer (score 0):

You should still be able to run the iOS simulator, which is generally the default behaviour for the build-and-run button - you can download more simulator environments in Xcode -> Preferences -> Components if you're missing one that you need.

Update: If you want third parties to run the app, there's no practical option apart from TestFlight. This is because iOS uses code signing to prevent trojan or pirated apps being installed on their devices. In that case you can consider other options which will achieve whatever your goals are, for example making a video of the app in use or setting up VNC access to a machine with the simulator (and code) on it.

Comment: but how can I send this to someone without sending the code along?

Comment: If you want to send the app to a third party, TestFlight is essentially your only option. If you somehow got the app files to somebody they would not be run because they aren't signed by the store, and it's unlikely that you could get it straight to a simulator on their computer without a very long and technical process. I'll update my answer, didn't realise that you meant that you want third parties to access the app.